# Extracting a column from a paragraph from a csv file using java

Tags: java, csv, extract

```
MAJOR ACC NO,MINOR ACC NO,STD CODE,TEL NO,DIST CODE
7452145,723456,  01,4213036,AAA
7254287,7863265,  01,2121920,AAA


FRUNDTE,FMACNO,FACCNO,FDISTCOD,FBILSEQ,FOOCTYP,FOOCDES,FOOCAMT,FSTD,FTELNO,FNORECON,FXFRACCN,FLANGIND,CUR
12345,71234,7643234,AAA,001,DX,WLR Promotion - Insitu /Pre-Cabled PSTN Connection,-37.87,,,0,,E,EUR


FRUNDTE,FMACNO,FACCNO,FDISTCOD,FBILSEQ,FORDNO,FREF,FCHGDES,FCHGAMT,CUR,FORENFRM,FORENTO
3242241,72349489,2345352,AAA,001,30234843P ,1,NEW CONNECTION - PRECABLED CHARGE,37.87,EUR,2123422,201201234
12123471,7618412389,76333232,AAA,001,3123443P ,2,BROKEN PERIOD RENTAL,5.40,EUR,201234523,20123601
```

I have a csv file something like the one above and I want to extract certain columns from it. For example I want to extract the first column of the first paragraph. I'm kind of new to java but I am able to read the file but I want to extract certain columns from different paragraphs. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use a CSV processing API. I think Apache Foundation has one.

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/15128402/1283215